# runOnUiThread without Activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-runonuithread

I have created an java class in android studio and I want to use runOnUiThread() in this class.
Can I run runOnUiThread() thread without Activity.xml in Android? 
If Answer is yes? than how?

Answer (score 14):

Yes. You just need to use `Handler`.

```
 new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                }
            });
```

Comment: with this code snippet i can update UI?

Comment: @nisarg yes, you can

Comment: Also instead of calling `new Runnable() { }`, You can use a lambda: `() -> { }`